# Why custom JDBC driver doesn't work in integration tests with Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, jdbc

I'm making custom JDBC driver and I need to test it (with Spring-boot). I added a dependency (I use Maven) this driver JAR to another project and it's work fine in the main program. But when I'm trying to make integration tests (in unit tests the driver registered in `DriverManager` by itself) driver doesn't load so Spring-boot can't create bean with name 'dataSource'.

I also tried to write unit tests to use the driver directly, but the driver cannot load the properties file that is contained in the resources (file path is `src/main/resources/driver.properties`). In this case the driver registered in `DriverManager` by itself.

How can I make it so that:

1. The driver can see the file from resources during unit tests? ***FIXED***
2. The driver start register itself during integration tests with Spring?

Note: JDBC use the service provider mechanism to load drivers, so I also have the `java.sql.Driver` file in resources.(`src/main/resources/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`).

[Link for the JDBC driver code. Readme have also link to project, where I'm trying to test driver](https://github.com/V31R/jdbc-mock-driver/tree/check_driver_work)

Code of test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationSmokeTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoad(){
        
        assertTrue(true);

    }

}
```

In main program driver is loaded and spring work with them fine.

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>HttpDriver</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: `new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/driver-mock.properties");` is wrong. You aren't loading a file. A file in the sense of a `java.io.File` which needs to be a resource ont he filesystem. Yours is on the class path inside a jar file. Instead use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("driver.propertier")`. And read on how one should read resources in Java and what a resource and file is in this case.

Comment: In integration tests with spring the driver still doesn't registered

Comment: Is the driver on the class path and is the service loader file included in the proper location in that jar.

Comment: Yes, otherwise the driver would not be loaded anywhere. There are problem only in spring boot integration tests. In main program spring boot works fine with the driver

Comment: If it isn't loaded it isn't on the class path. So I suspect the error is in your test setup. But as you left that out that will be impossible to answer.

Comment: Driver not a spring bean, it must loaded by service provider mechanism. And it does in unit tests and main program. Are there any features of SPI working in integration spring boot tests?

Comment: Where do I state it needs to be a bean? As stated if it isn't loaded it isn't on the class path so you must be doing something weird in your test. For debugging you could set a logger to the `DriverManager` and see more closely what's happens. Adding `DriverManager.setLogWrite(new PrintWriter(System.out))`; Please add the configuration for Spring Boot as well as your dependencies as well.

Comment: DriverManager simply checks all registered drivers. My driver is not registered, as if SPI does not see META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver in integration tests

Comment: The problem turned out to be elsewhere - application property profiles. Thank you very much for your help